# Comparing clusters of timestamps

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have data from a user study that I'm struggling to know how best to analyse.

Participants were asked to manually organise a set of images into clusters (i.e. a group of related objects). Those artefacts had (unseen) creation timestamps associated with them. Participants repeated the task in 3 conditions, with three different artefact sets each time. They were permitted to create as many clusters as they wished, of arbitrary length.

I'd like to establish if the timestamps in the clusters differ between the three conditions (i.e. does one condition lead participants to organise the artefacts more temporally than others). I'm not interested in the time values themselves, but in the scale of the differences between them.

My current approach is to compute timestamp differences for every unique pair of images within every cluster. Each condition is then represented by a set of clusters (i.e. `Cond1 = Clus1, Clus2... Clusn)`), each described as a list of timestamp differences (i.e `Clus1 = (abs(Timestamp1-Timestamp2), abs(Timestamp1-Timestamp3), abs(Timestamp1-Timestamp4)... abs(Timestampn-1-Timestampn))`.

Given the above, I can then calculate the range, mean, and standard deviation of each cluster, and average the resulting values within a condition.

I have relatively limited statistical knowledge but I feel like there must be a more appropriate (and elegant) technique to apply here, if only I knew what it was! Looking around here on Cross Validated and the wider Web it seems like I might be looking for a difference measure?

Can anyone advise about exactly what I should be using to compare the data in these conditions?

--- Additional Info (added 1/19) ---

The artefacts here are photographs given to participants in a different order in each condition (the order they were taken in, a random order, and one other ordering).

The overall research question is exploring whether presenting the images to participants in different orders leads them to cluster them differently, or whether the participants tend towards clustering them according to the time that the images were taken regardless of the presentation order.

Comment: Could you add the overall research question or aim of your study? As I am not sure in which direction you want to go, there is an abundance of statistics which might be applicable or not.

Comment: Done -- does that help?

Comment: Clusters don't typically have an order. Your description of timestamp differences (abs(t_i - t_j) ...) seems to capture the spread of the cluster in some sense.  It might be sufficient to use standard deviation of timestamps to capture a sense of spread.  A particular cluster could perhaps be summarized with its sample mean, standard deviation, and observation count. As to modeling the clustering process, in machine learning the clustering process is sometimes modeled as a "Chinese restaurant process".  You might characterize/estimate the clustering processes under your three conditions.